# Error runing Xcode build on Flutter using TensorFlowLite

Tags: ios, flutter, tensorflow

I'm creating an app on Flutter using the TensorFlowLite library and after finishing all the Flutter Code, I'm trying to debug it on a iOS Simulator and on the console I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/13/q8h3_c012wvc3mxcfpzrf6fr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.8a658a/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirNlQoAO/temporary_xcresult_bundle
/Users/chrisley/terminal-addons/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite-1.1.2/ios/Classes/TflitePlugin.mm:20:9: fatal error: 'TensorFlowLiteC.h' file not found
    #import "TensorFlowLiteC.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: the following command failed with exit code 1 but produced no further output
CompileC /Users/chrisley/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-eguofderrkwgjseuiagmsjusmxtx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/tflite.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TflitePlugin.o /Users/chrisley/terminal-addons/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite-1.1.2/ios/Classes/TflitePlugin.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'tflite' from project 'Pods')
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/chrisley/Documents/Development/Flutter/tensorflow_test/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'TensorFlowLiteC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/13/q8h3_c012wvc3mxcfpzrf6fr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.8a658a/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirNlQoAO/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'TensorFlowLiteC.h' file not found
/Users/chrisley/terminal-addons/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite-1.1.2/ios/Classes/TflitePlugin.mm:19:8
2

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

I tried to solve the error adding `pod 'TensorFlowLiteObjC'` in the *Podfile* but it didn't work.

Comment: did you try run command `pod install`?

Comment: Where I should run it? Because, I only tried putting pod `'TensorFlowLiteObjC' ` in the Podfile

Comment: `cd` to your `ios` directory, then run `pod install`. If your mac is using Apple M1 Pro chip then run `arch -x86_64 pod install`

Comment: Have you added TensorFlowLiteC.framework in your pub-cache? And also are you using any flutter package for this.?

Comment: @HeIsDying the pod install command didn't work :c

Comment: @Maqsood How I can add `TensorFlowLiteC.framework` in the pub cache?